# Unable to display an image in Photo or Gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to display a photo from a file located in the app directory but it's not displayed, on Photo I get an endless spinning circle and on Gallery an exclamation mark.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

provider_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="Attachments" path="Attachments" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

        myButton.setOnClickListener(){

            val path = File(filesDir, "Attachments")
            val fileName = File(path, "eiffel.jpg")

            val data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    fileName
            )
            this.grantUriPermission(
                    this.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    data,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            );

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*")

            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No activity to handle this type of intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I'm not getting any error nor app crash, just can't make it work.

Help will be strongly appreciated.

[image: Photo app]
[image]

Comment: @blackapps - I don't understand why the title is wrong, I didn't write anything about uploading but LOADING an image into Photo or Gallery - Both external app.
Beside your comment, can you provide a solution?

Comment: @blackapps - Here you go, I corrected the tile. Do you have a solution now?

Comment: The title is still wrong as you are trying to let your image be displayed by an external app using ACTION_VIEW. Its the user who decides which image viewer will be used. Remove the grandUriPermission call and use intent.setFlag to set that flag.

Comment: @blackapps - Did what you suggested and still the same, I'm getting either an exclamation mark if I choose "Gallery" or an endless spinning for "Photo"

Comment: Add: if(!fileName.exists()) return; Display a Toast too then. Tell the value of data.toString() please. Update your code here too.

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity

```
    package com.example.imageviewer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button, button2;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }
    public void b1click (View v)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
    public void b2click(View v){
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bm,".",".");
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer the question in multiple answers. You can write as much as you want in one. Also, give appropriate reasons to support your answer

Answer (score 0):

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imageviewer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still don't understand why I can't load an image from my internal storage but I'm able to do it from my external one.

Comment: In your xml file only internal path is specified.